# Get published Office 365 calendar JSON without OAuth2 step?

Tags: rest, oauth, calendar, office365

**Edit:**

Initially, the question was how to get an Office365 calendar in JSON without authentication; but, what I meant was how to get an Office365 calendar in JSON without requiring the OAuth2 step (so, for example on the server-side other authentication methods are acceptable to retrieve the calendar data).

**Problem:**

I would like to use the Office 365 REST API to access this published calendar (i.e. the "read" operation only since the calendar is published), so that I can "style" the calendar the way I prefer. So, I am looking for a public API approach to using one of my calendars. The code examples for the Office 365 REST API that I found use OAuth to authenticate the client. This seems like overkill.

I have come up with some possible solutions, so any suggestions on the best approach is welcome.

**Background:**

I have a published calendar in Office365, which gives me a feed:

http://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/USER@DOMAIN/CALENDAR_NAME/calendar.ics

and the URL:

http://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/USER@DOMAIN/CALENDAR_NAME/calendar.html

How can I do what "calendar.html" is doing, so that I can display a calendar the way I would like it to be displayed (instead of IFraming what Office365 provides)?

**Example:**

Here is an example URL using the REST API:

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/USER@DOMAIN/calendars

The browser will bring up a basic authentication dialog, so it looks like OAuth is not the only method required (one possible solution, the request could be proxied from a local server that is calling the REST API using basic authentication).

**Issues:**

- One issue might be that the calendar "publishing" feature is meant for a limited amount of data (e.g. 1 year prior or in the future at the most) which is what I assume is what the iCalendar (*.ics) file would contain for any request.
- Using the REST API with authentication assumes that there isn't a date range restriction (since one can query the calendar using the REST API, I assume you could query further back than a year).

**Possible solutions:**

- Proxy the request from another server by making the REST API calls using basic authentication. Caching might also be needed since it appears the response times could be slow. The calendar could be either JavaScript that consumes a local endpoint, or HTML content generated at the server.
- It looks like the Office365 **AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync()** will accept a **ClientCredential** (client id and secret) or also a **UserCredential** (simple username and password). So, I think I can run a local proxy service that uses the Office365 library by manually passing in credentials to the function that acquires a token. (I still need to test this to make sure that the function will indeed work this way.)
- <strike>Simply iFrame the "calendar.html" page provide by Office 365.</strike> (Cross domain is prevented, unless it's on one of the Microsoft hosted solutions "Something Webs".)
- <strike>If using the iCalendar (*.ics) feed, then one would need a transformation function for the iCalendar format to JSON (https://github.com/kewisch/ical.js), then JavaScript or a calendar library could be used to design a custom calendar.</strike> (This wouldn't be very convenient for viewing a year's worth of calendar events without cashing and providing a querying mechanism, except for displaying one month back and forward. So, some sort of ics2json to use on FullCalendar might work for only a couple months of calendar history.)

Any suggestions on the best approach (or another approach not listed here) is welcome.

Comment: I haven't been able to get AcquireTokenAsync to work with just the UserCredential. So, it looks like making manual REST API calls using basic authentication is looking more workable at the moment.

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this? I'm in the same boat. Looking to style a calendar but the event updates need to be automated. The application wont be accessed directly by users (it will be displayed on digital signage) so I cant really afford the whole OAuth process for acccessing the data.

Comment: It has been a while, but I had to proxy the request, and then I am not sure what authentication method I used, but I did use the Office 365 libraries, and created a wrapper class to get just what I needed to use.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I ended up using their SOAP api with a wrapper.

Comment: @KFE how you achieve this ? i'm in the same boat. can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: @manish1706  I used this library as a starting point: https://github.com/rileydutton/Exchange-Web-Services-for-PHP

Comment: +1 @KFE for response. i have used given library but at point when it ask "download the SOAP files from your Exchange server" and i am not able to download any SOAP files from server. can you please help me to achieve this

Comment: manish, are you still needing the files? I can send you the files.

Comment: @manish1706 Here are all of the required files for the above library, including the types.xsd, messages.xsd, and services.wsdl file required to get up and running. https://www.dropbox.com/s/04cwfihodhq6sj2/ews.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

The Office 365 APIs require Oauth2 in order to function. If you are using Visual Studio to develop your app, the O365 tools for Visual Studio + OWIN middleware will handle a lot of the oauth work for you.

If oauth is absolutely not an option, I'd consider using the EWS APIs instead, which can use basic authentication (more info on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019(v=exchg.150).aspx) on MSDN).

Comment: OAuth is definitely an option. In fact, I am more interested in using a library than parsing HTTP responses by hand.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Could you provide some more information on what it would take to setup OWIN for the scenario you are talking about in the first option? Also, I do like the idea of using EWS API if it allows for Basic Authentication. Reading their docs they mention needing a Developer Site subscription (I think that is rolled into Business Premium, which I don't have), so I assume this isn't necessary with the Basic Authentication. The code samples are pretty complex. Do you know where I can find an example of just the Basic Auth + a query (like for calendar events)?

Comment: FWIW I *very* strongly recommend against using basic auth for anything as even the most basic man-in-the-middle attacks will leave your creds wide open. I also very strongly recommend *for* using the O365 APIs instead of EWS if possible as it won't box you in to only accessing Exchange data like the EWS APIs will. The OWIN middleware framework is a simple nuget package that you can include in your projects. We have an example of how to use OWIN to access contacts data (so, info from exchange) via the O365 APIs located at https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant

Comment: In addition - re: the developer site - you only need a developer site if you are developing apps for SharePoint or want to use a SP-based app catalog to deploy apps for Office. You do NOT need a dev site if you want to use the O365 APIs (it's confusing, I know).

Finally - to take a look at what fetching calendar data will look like using the O365 tools, take a look at the O365 API sandbox located at https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/. It's like six lines of code in JavaScript and you can run the sandbox against your O365 data if you are a tenant admin.